# Generating text files from a batch with two variables

Tags: batch-file

I am new to scripting but I would like some advice please.

I have a text file which has two variables in that I am altering by using replace in notepad but I would like to automate this by using a batch file to capture the two variables from the user and generate a text file.

If possible I would also like the script to paste them into a specific location but that is a secondary concern at the moment.

```
@Echo Off
Title Host File Generator

pause

cd\

cd\Test

ren lmhost lmhost.old

ren host host.old

ren config.ini config.ini.old

pause

set /p ip=Please enter the first three octets of the stores IP address? 

(
  echo IP address: %ip%.71
  echo Line1
  echo Line2
  echo Last Line
) > Host.txt

set /p storenumber=Please enter the store number as a four digit number eg 0209, 1404 etc 

(
  echo Store Number: UK0%storenumber%
  echo Line3
  echo Line4
  echo Last Line
) >> Host.txt

Pause
```

The pause commands are in there so I know where the script is up to while I develop it.

From what I am reading I need the entire contents of the text file in the script with echo commands at the start of every line is this correct or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I've added all the text I want to generate into the script using the echo command and redirecting to a text file but this seems messy. I don't know how to alter the variables either so they appear where they need to be in the text file.

Comment: @DanielNeocleous, we would really need to see an example of the text file and what needs to be replaced in it.

Comment: @Echo Off
Title Host File Generator

set /p ip=Please enter the first three octets of the stores IP address? 

(
  echo IP address: %ip%.71
  echo Line1
  echo Line2
  echo Last Line
) > Host.txt

set /p storenumber=Please enter the store number as a four digit number eg 0209, 1404 etc 

(
  echo Store Number: UK0%storenumber%
  echo Line3
  echo Line4
  echo Last Line
) >> Host.txt

Pause

Comment: append your comment to the original question

Comment: @PA apologies I have added it to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the additional lines are all static, then you could just append them onto the file without a separate `echo` for each line.

```
set /p ip=Please enter the first three octets of the stores IP address? 
(
  echo IP address: %ip%.71
  TYPE IP_FILE_LINES.txt
) > Host.txt

set /p storenumber=Please enter the store number as a four digit number eg 0209, 1404 etc 
(
  echo Store Number: UK0%storenumber%
  TYPE STORE_FILE_LINES.txt
) >> Host.txt
```

Comment: Pretty much every line has a variable in. I've got the script working the way I wanted by generating the entire text file out of the script.  It may not be the most elegant script but it works. I'm quite happy for my first scripting attempt, there was some excellent help on here in other posts that made it possible.